# Find $E[VY]$ where V is a continuous RV and $Y$ is a discrete RV.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $V \sim R(0,1)$ be uniform continuous and $Y$ discrete with density: $\frac 1 4$ if $y=0$, $\frac 3 4$ if $y=1$.

Find $E[VY]:$

I know $P(VY = 0)=\frac 1 4$ and $P(0<VY\le 1) = \frac 3 4$. Also $VY$ is a RV with support $[0,  1]$. But how do I use this to find $E[VY]$ ? I've trouble deciding how to calculate this expectation, but I could use $h(V,Y) = VY$ ?

Comment: Are they independent?

Comment: I know $U,V$ are independent, where $Y$ is defined as follows $Y = 0$ if $U < \frac 1 2$, $Y=1$ if $U \ge \frac 1 2$.

Comment: Does this imply $V,Y$ are also independent ? Why ?

Answer (score 0):

The *law of total expectation* says that $$
  E(VY) = E(VY \mid Y = 0)P(Y = 0) + E(VY \mid Y = 1)P(Y = 1) \text{.}
$$
Thus, $$\begin{eqnarray}
  E(VY) &=& \underbrace{E(0 \mid Y=0)}_{=0}\tfrac{1}{4} + E(V \mid Y = 1)\tfrac{3}{4} \\
  &=& \tfrac{3}{4}E(V \mid Y = 1) \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Without assuming the independence of $V,Y$ you can't go any further. If, say $Y$ is 1 exactly if $V > \frac{1}{4}$, then $E(VY) = \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}1\right) = \frac{15}{32}$. If, OTOH, $Y$ is 1 exactly if $V < \frac{3}{4}$, then  $E(VY) = \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2}0\right) = \frac{9}{32}$.

If, however, $V,Y$ are independent, then $E(V | Y = 1) = E(V) = \frac{1}{2}$, you therefore get $$
  E(VY) = \frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{8}\text{.}
$$
You get the same if you merely assume that $V,Y$ are uncorrelated, because then $E(VY) = E(V)E(Y)$ and thus $$
  E(VY) = E(V)E(Y) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{8} \text{.}
$$